# Jenkins AZ command not found

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, azure-cli

JenkinsFile

```
import hudson.model.*


SERVICE_PRINCIPAL = env.SERVICE_PRINCIPAL
SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET = env.SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET
TENTANT_ID = env.TENTANT_ID
SUBSCRIPTION = env.SUBSCRIPTION
SSH_KEY = env.SSH_KEY

timestamps {
    node('master') {
        stage("Cleanup existing Jenkins workspace") {
            sh "rm -rf ./*"
        }
        stage('Build') {
                echo 'Building..'
            
        }
        stage('Test') {
                echo 'Testing..'
                sh"""
                    # clear previous instances
                    az account clear;
                    # az login
                    az login --service-principal -u ${SERVICE_PRINCIPAL} -p ${SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_SECRET} --tenant ${TENTANT_ID};
                    # set client subscription
                    az account set --subscription ${SUBSCRIPTION};
                    az account list --output table;
                """
            
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Respons

```
00:08:33  Testing..
[Pipeline] sh
00:08:33  + az account clear
00:08:33  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Install_AKS@tmp/durable-922f3b47/script.sh: 3: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Install_AKS@tmp/durable-922f3b47/script.sh: az: not found
```

I already installed Azure CLI plugin and added Azure SP credentials in Jenkins
This Jenkins is running based on an jenkins immage **jenkins/jenkins:lts**

```
jenkins@a642e1a7ba69:/$ az login
bash: az: command not found
jenkins@a642e1a7ba69:/$
```

I tried to uninstall and install Azure CLI from jenkins platform and delete the container and create a new one.
I am open to any suggestions :)

Comment: You need to install the `az cli` in the jenkins agent 

Comment: Hey, I already tried to install it from michrosoft documentation   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?view=azure-cli-latest&pivots=apt by using curl comand

`jenkins@2b4e70c3bc55:/$ curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
bash: sudo: command not found`

Comment: Which OS are your agents running?

Comment: is running on linux

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?  If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the details, it seems you can't install the Azure CLI through the command `curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash bash`. I guess you use the container as the agent, maybe it's the Azure Container Instance. If I'm right, then here are two solutions for you.

One is that change the command into `curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash`. The ACI uses the root user to run the command, so you don't need the command `sudo`.

Another one is that uses the master node to run the task. Of course, you need to install the Azure CLI plugins and install Azure CLI command in the master node.